# Reading from csv file in Go only prints last line

Tags: csv, go

I'm trying to read contents from a csv file. I have the following but when I run the code it only prints the last line of the csv file.

```
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("data.csv")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    r := csv.NewReader(f)

    for {
        record, err := r.Read()

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}

// Returns
10 3311 74209 OM209] site
```

What am I doing wrong?

**data.csv**

```
Item,clientid,ident,site
1,2493,83982,OM221
2,2509,85764,OM201
3,2535,70264,OM205
4,2608,70648,OM205
5,2766,83647,OM304
6,2871,69400,OM201
7,2933,80024,OM201
8,2994,77827,OM301
9,3206,73315,OM201
10,3311,74209,OM209
```

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: It works perfectly for me, with your exact code and that CSV data.

Comment: Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/KYDxC0vQ0e

Comment: @Flimzy in your example you've changed the code so the contents is a string variable so do you think there must be something happening in the way the file is being read and passed to the csv.NewReader?

Comment: No, it works fine when I read it from the file, too. I just put it in a string variable so it would work in the playground.

Comment: @Flimzy actually just noticed (and updated post) that I get a strange return. There are a random closing square bracket and the last column heading. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have proper line endings? Windows still botches these up.

Comment: @Volker, I'm on osx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Volker for the mention about proper line endings.

My csv file was created with an old version of Excel for Mac which apparently has issues with creating proper line endings.

> On a Mac, Excel produces csv files with the wrong line endings, which causes problems for git (amongst other things).This issue plagues at least Excel 2008 and 2011, and possibly other versions. Basically, saving a file as comma separated values (csv) uses a carriage return \r rather than a line feed \n as a newline. Way back before OS X, this was actually the correct Mac file ending, but after the move to be more unix-y, the correct line ending should be \n. Given that nothing has used this as the proper line endings for over a decade, this is a bug.

https://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-04-30-excel-and-line-endings/

Creating a new file blank file and pasting in the contents fixed it.